# How make reference to keys in dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say, I have a dictionary like below

```
dik = {
    "dir1": {},
}
```

I am interested to traverse through the dictionary recursively from value of one key to value of another.

```
# assume `dik` as global variable

def travel():
   curr = dik
   for i in ["dir1", "dir2"]:
       if i in curr:
          curr = curr[i]
       else:
          curr[i] = {}
```

I want the travel function to make the `dik` as

```
dik = {
    "dir1": {
        "dir2": {}
    },
}
```

Comment: The code you've just written does what you want, doesn't it? `t = dik["dir2"]; t["dir3"] = whatever` will change the value in `dik` as well.

Comment: To elaborate on what Kevin, said `t` would be a reference to the dictionary at the key `dik["dir2"]`.

Comment: If we have this assignment expressions in a function, while `dik` as a global variable, then it would not work. Let me describe clearly in the question

Comment: It doesn't matter if `dik` is global or local; `t` and `dik["dir2"]` refer to the exact same object.

Comment: @chepner can you look at the question again please. I have rewritten it. Last time, I am afraid, I haven't made it clear

Comment: Same thing; if `curr` initially refers to `dik`, it will next be set to `dik['dir1]`, so that `curr` and `dik['dir1']` refer to the exact same dictionary. As a result, `curr['dir2'] = {}` will do the same thing as `dik['dir1']['dir2'] = {}`. The only thing to watch out for is that something like `t = dik['dir1']; t = {}` would *not* set `dik['dir1']` to `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine, even with a function, due to the mutability of dictionaries.

```
>>> dik = {
        "dir1": {},
        "dir2": {
            "dir3": {},
            "dir4": {
                "dir5": {}
                    }
                }
          }
>>> print dik
{'dir2': {'dir3': {}, 'dir4': {'dir5': {}}}, 'dir1': {}}

>>> def change(d, key, val):
        d[key] = val
```

This function takes any dictionary and sets or creates key with the value 'val'. You can pass nested dictionaries and it can access them fine, and it will be reflected in the global dik.

```
>>> change(dik['dir2']['dir3'], "file", "Some text")
>>> print dik
{'dir2': {'dir3': {'file': 'Some text'}, 'dir4': {'dir5': {}}}, 'dir1': {}}
```

Note it also still works if you use a reference in the function, like your `curr = dik`, because that just tells Python to treat them as the same thing, it doesn't actually make a separate copy.

Answer (score 2):

Just doing some quick testing this is what I got. (The behavior should be what you have described I believe)

```
>>> dik = {
...     "dir1": {},
...     "dir2": {
...         "dir3": {},
...         "dir4": {
...             "dir5": {}
...         }
...     }
... }
>>> t = dik['dir2']
>>> t
{'dir3': {}, 'dir4': {'dir5': {}}}
>>> t['dir3'] = {'here' : 5}
>>> t
{'dir3': {'here': 5}, 'dir4': {'dir5': {}}}
>>> dik
{'dir2': {'dir3': {'here': 5}, 'dir4': {'dir5': {}}}, 'dir1': {}}
```

Comment: Though what you wrote is correct, the asker has since clarified that they were asking about with dictionaries being changed in functions. So it might be worth noting how this behaviour is the same even in a function.